How to have multiple versions of website (with different type of content)?
I need a little bit of help. I'm working on a Django project, it's like a blog. I have implemented localization and added couple languages. Now I would like to develop a customized content for specific regions.
Current set up it like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/
I have one content in 3 languages:
content 
     - en (English) - http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/
     - de (German) - http://127.0.0.1:8000/de/
     - ar (Arabic) - http://127.0.0.1:8000/ar/

I used django-parler so every article can be provided in all 3 languages.
Now I'd like to have more content - let's say content specific to specific region, it would look like this:
Global content
     - en (English) - http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/glo/ (content on English for global readers)
     - de (German) - http://127.0.0.1:8000/de/glo/ (content German for global readers)
     - ar (Arabic) - http://127.0.0.1:8000/ar/glo/ (content on Arabic for global readers)

German content
     - en (English) - http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/de/ (content on English for German region)
     - de (German) - http://127.0.0.1:8000/de/de/ (content German for German region)
     - ar (Arabic) - http://127.0.0.1:8000/ar/de/ (content on Arabic for German region)

Middle East content
     - en (English) - http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/me/ (content on English for Middle East readers)
     - de (German) - http://127.0.0.1:8000/de/me/ (content German for Middle East readers)
     - ar (Arabic) - http://127.0.0.1:8000/ar/me/ (content on Arabic for Middle East readers)

I would incorporate on menu;

"I speak this language and I want to see this content".

Models would do same thing, I don't think that there would be many exemptions.
I noticed that django website has same approach, if we look at the link: docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2
"en" at the end of the domain is language and 4.2 is version, I'm looking how to implement version part on my website.
I found the django "sites" framework but it doesn't make sense to me. Please could you guide me on how to do this? Is there any tutorial or is there a specific name for this?
Thanks in advance!

After much research, I realized that my current method is not good. DO NOT USE IT. I will come up with a standard approach.

I come up with something different, but I'd like to see your standard approach.
